# Django Model Form not saving NULL data

Tags: python, django, ajax, postgresql

I have the following form, view and model form, the Django version is 3.0 and the original DB is written in PostgreSQL, the form is submitted via ajax.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    depth = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    from_field = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    to = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    interval = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False

class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['depth', 'from_field', 'to', 'interval']

@csrf_exempt
def AddData(request):
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

When AddData is executed there is no errors but with the data being something like:

```
depth=30, from_field=null, to=null, interval=null
```

The data saved in the database is:

```
depth=30, from_field=0, to=null, interval=null
```

Could this be because the model has the parameter managed=False? I've checked the data sent by the template and when it's received by the view and the null data reflects correctly in DB except for from field.

Comment: Does field have default value in database

Comment: As far as I've seen it doesn't have a default value.